# How to change the local code Link?

Tags: uri

I am using the Aqcuia Dev Desktop where near to the **local code label** is written the following link: ( `C:\Users\Wessam\DrupalSites\devdesktop\drupal-7.34` )

lets say that i want to move my **drupal localhost site files & folders** to another folder so it will be under the following link: ( `C:\Users\Wessam\AllSites\CompanyName` ) so the **link near to the local code label** should be changed also...

How to do the mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

1)

Follow the Path below:

C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\AcquiaDevDesktop\datamodel.xml

2)

Open the " datamodel.xml " using the Notepad++ or any other similar programming language editor program

3)

Edit the Link written within:

HERE HERE HERE

HERE HERE HERE

to any link required by you .

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no problem if you have a good programming! Clearly the url of your local site will be changed but the question is, how did you refer to your site?

I mean if the old url is `localhost/old-version`, Have you ever used this url in your template files or js files? if yes then you should replace  them by new url. I recommend you to use

```
<?php 
      global $base_url;
?>
```

I have moved my website from a server to another server with new domain and no problem happened (only some trivial changes were needed) because I always use relative paths.